# Moving UI Controls of GoogleMap, while not moving the visible region

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

I want to move the *mylocation*-Button of an GoogleMap in android from the top-right to the bottom-right corner of the display.

The [android APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#map_padding) offer this function to do this.

> GoogleMap.setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)

My problem is that

> - **getCameraPosition()** will return the center of the padded region.
> - **Projection.getVisibleRegion()** will return the padded region.

So after the user touches the "myLocation"-Button, the users location is not in the center of the map anymore.

**What is the best way to move the UI-Controls, but leave the visible Region unpadded?**

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GoogleMap.set padding()` seems to only make sense if want for example split your screen so that the map only covers a part of it.

So what I did so solve this is create my own `my-location` button that responds to a click like this:

**Layout.xml**

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myLocation"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_my_position" />
```

**implementing `onLocationChanged()` so that I always have access to my current location**

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.currentLocation = location;
}
```

**my-location clickListener**:

```
myPosition = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.myLocation);
myPosition.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(currentLocation
                .getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude())));
    }
});
```